# Aggregating multiple events on the same date

Tags: r, dplyr

I have event log data that looks like this:

```
  id       date  order_value
   1 2015-01-01   19.42
   1 2015-01-22   21.23
   1 2015-07-14   54.16
   1 2015-08-13   36.28
   2 2015-01-01   13.55
   2 2015-03-15   16.77
   2 2015-03-15   21.31
```

Notice how id2 has 2 events on the same date. I want to sum those but I'm at a total loss.

I tried to use dplyr but I don't see any logical constructs that will let me do this. I think I have to use some sort of an if-statement, but I've heard those should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Any dplyr tutorial will cover aggregation. `DF %>% group_by(id,date) %>% summarise(v = sum(order_value))` ....

Comment: I was reading the ?help functions and did not realize I can use 2 grouping variables. Seems to have worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if-statement were you thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can use `group_by` and `summarize` to do this task:

```
library(dplyr);

df_grouped    <- group_by(df, id, date);
df_summarized <- summarize(df_grouped, order_value_per_date = sum(order_value));
df_summarized;
```